# Xcode odd behaiviour and bad rendering code

Tags: xcode, bug

Recently I'm experiencing some odd behavior from Xcode. It jump up and down on its own, it does not render codes correctly.
Like this screenshot ↓

[image: Xcode screenshot - odd behavior]

It's driving me crazy. Have this ever occurred to anybody else?
Is there a solution?

P.S. this problem happens with both Objective-C and Objective-C++ and with every theme I use. (Currently I'm using xcode 6.3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that was a bug at XCode 6. Since XCode 7 I have not encountered this problem.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but this still happens to me in xcode 7.3.1, so perhaps the downvoter had a similar experience

Comment: This bug is happening to me in Xcode 8.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the **Show live issues** checkbox in **Xcode > Preferences > General** (found near the top of the panel).

I was experiencing the same issue. I found this answer through [Editor glitch when editing near end of long file](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12756) in Apple's Developer Forums.

It worked for me running Xcode 7.3 with a 2706 line file. The glitch happened around line 2250.

Comment: I hate having to disable a feature, but it did fix the problem. It was happening to me in a file of only 435 lines.